# jQuery: get div instance number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to get the instance number of a div, e.g. I have 4 instances of the `.test` div, and using `.length` just generates `4`. But I want to put the instance number in each div, for example the 3rd instance of the `.test` div would have a `3` in it and so on. 
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/YrtjF/

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var n = $(".test").length;

    $('.test').html(n);

});
```

If this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the version of [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) that takes a function as the parameter

```
$('.test').html(function (i) {
    return i + 1
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6gXP9/)

Comment: Your's is actually better...rs

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var n = 1;
$('.test').each(function() {
    $(this).html(n);
   n++; 
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".test").html(function(i,v){
       return i+1;
    });    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/YrtjF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use each method here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".test").each(function(i){
    $(this).html(i +1);
    });
});
```